# How to edit data with django-tables2 in a frontend?

Tags: python, django, frontend, editing, django-tables2

I have a Django and i want to create CRM system, allowing users to view, add, delete and edit data in a front-end. I found nice module, named django-tables2, which allows displaying nice tables of my data:

> django-tables2 turns data into HTML tables. Features:
>
> Pagination Ordering Extendable Class based view Supports for queryset
>   and list data Themes

So my question is what is the best way to make front-end editing with this tables?
For example: i want to make  records from table be selectable with checkboxes and then i want them to be deletable and editable, like in django built-in admin. In other words: i need some tool like django-admin but in my front-end (in my template). 
So do i need to write js to handle user clicks on table records and point this actions to my urls/views or there is a better way?Hope this question will help not only my but anyone who planning to became frontend-ninja, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at [Swampdragon](http://www.swampdragon.net) and Angular.  They might integrate nicely with django-tables2.  You can always just write the table with Angular.